# How to read xml nodes values by using the dynamic sql query method "EXECUTE sp_executesql"

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

## Declare the XML here

```
DECLARE @input XML 
set @input= '<AcordXML><location id="1"><id>1</id><name>first</name><noofemp>37</noofemp> </location></AcordXML>'
```

## Set the dynamic query

```
Declare @Equery varchar(max)
set @Equery='SELECT C.value(''name[1]'',''varchar(MAX)''), C.value(''noofemp[1]'', ''varchar(MAX)'') FROM @input.nodes(''//location'') AS T(C)'
    print @Equery
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Equery, N'@input varchar(max)',@input=@input
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Might be, there's a better way...

Comment: @shnugo what should be other way

Comment: Why do you need this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Declare proc @input parameter as XML , the same type you are really passing

```
DECLARE @input XML 
SET @input = '<AcordXML > <location id="1"><id>1</id> <name>first</name><noofemp>37</noofemp> </location></AcordXML>'

DECLARE @Equery nvarchar(max)
SET @Equery = 'SELECT C.value(''name[1]'',''varchar(MAX)''), C.value(''noofemp[1]'', ''varchar(MAX)'') FROM @input.nodes(''//location'') AS T(C)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Equery, N'@input XML',@input=@input
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing in this is passing the parameter only, at first you can see the DECLARE of XML parameter @Persons with data type XML, then you will have to declare the statement of the sql query itself-  make sure to wrap it with single quot, the tricky part is when you execute, make sure to add the parameters as follows:
1- @stmt is the string query to execute
2- define the parameter inside your query.
3- assign the value of this parameter from the initialized parameter as @XMLPersons = @PersonsXml

that's it and you'r good to go

```
DECLARE @PersonsXml XML = '<persons > <person ><firstName > Jon </firstName ><lastName > Johnson </lastName > </person >
<person > <firstName >Kathy</firstName > <lastName > Carter </lastName > </person >
<person > <firstName > Bob </firstName > <lastName > Burns </lastName > </person > </persons >'

declare @stmt nvarchar(max)
set @stmt = N'Select person.value(''(firstName/text())[1]'',''nvarchar(100)'') as Mobile_Number  From @XMLPersons.nodes(''/persons/person'') as Persons(person)'

Execute sp_executesql @stmt, N'@XMLPersons xml' , @XMLPersons = @PersonsXml
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.